# asp.net using session in custom httpHandler

Tags: asp.net

i've a custom httphandler in app_code folder, i want to use session in this class but there is a exception message, here is the code

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    HttpRequest request = context.Request;
    HttpResponse response = context.Response;

    HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"] = "ABC";
    response.Write(HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"].ToString());

}
```

error message:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

anyone knows what is the problems>

Comment: Where does the error occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to eanable session state in HttpHandler you should inherit handler from marker interface [IRequiresSessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.irequiressessionstate.aspx)

```
   using System.Web.SessionState;

    public class handler: IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
    {

    }
```

Comment: After added: Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IRequiresSessionState' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?), missing using statment?

Comment: @hkinterview  using System.Web.SessionState; ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make your handler implement `IReadOnlySessionState` or `IRequiresSessionState` (for write access).

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement [`IReadOnlySessionState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.ireadonlysessionstate.aspx) to be able to access Session from an HttpHandler.

[Here's](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GettingSessionStateInHttpHandlersASHXFiles.aspx) a good example.

Note that there's no method to implement, simply make your handler implement the interface.